# Why isn't this basic java program working?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

The goal is to have it count the number of "xx" in the given string. We'll say that overlapping is allowed, so "xxx" contains 2 "xx".

See http://codingbat.com/prob/p194667
I can't seem to figure out why its not working

```
    int countXX(String str) {
        int f = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            if (!str.substring(i+1).isEmpty()){
                if (str.substring(i) == "x" && str.substring (i+1) == "x") {
                    f++;
                }
            }
        }
        return f;  
    }
```

Comment: This is a common mistake by starters. Be careful.

Comment: While it's wrong to compare string values with `==`, this question is more about the misuse of `substring` to extract a character.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question; it's not a duplicate of any common "==" vs. "equals" string comparison problem.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use == to compare strings; use equals().

```
int countXX(String str) {
    int f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (!str.substring(i+1).isEmpty()) {
            if (str.substring(i).equals("x") && str.substring(i+1).equals("x")) {
                f++;
            }
        }
    }
    return f;  
}
```

I think this code will still have a problem when `i` equals the length of the string minus 1 and you try to access the character at `(i+1)`.

Comment: .equals() still doesn't work

Comment: There's still the issue of misusing `substring` to extract a character from the string.

Comment: And i < str.length() - 1

Comment: equals works.  your code is borked.

Answer (score 4):

The `substring` method with one argument doesn't get just that character at that position, it gets everything from that position through to the end of the string.  Use `charAt` to get the character at that position, and compare it with `==` with the character literal `'x'`, not with the `String` `"x"`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use substring for indexing chars.

```
int countXX(String str) {
   int f = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) {
      if( str.charAt(i) == 'x' && str.charAt(i+1) == 'x' ) {
         f++;
      }
   }
   return f;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Three reasons:

1. substring() returns the whole string (so starting from "i" to the end of the string, and not only one letter).
2. Compare with .equals() and not ==
3. "i" should end at str.length() - 1

Answer (score 1):

Use the string's 'equals' method in stead of == :

```
int countXX(String str) {
    int f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if (!str.substring(i+1).isEmpty()){
    if (str.substring(i).equals("x") && str.substring (i+1).equals("x")) {
    f++;}}}
    return f;  
    }
```

Comment: This only partly solves problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
int countXX(String str) {
    int f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++){
        if (str.substring(i, i + 2).equals("xx")) {
            f++;
        }
    }
    return f;  
}
```